# How should you implement STL features for custom classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, overloading

I'm implementing a tuple-like class, call it `MyTuple`, and I would like it to have some STL features, namely `tuple_element`, `tuple_size`, and `get`.

1. Should I implement `tuple_element` and `tuple_size` specializations in `namespace std`? If not then how should I implement them?
2. Since I'm not allowed to overload the STL `get` function, does that mean I must provide a separate `get` function in my own namespace, thereby forcing users to write `using std::get;`?

Comment: You could write your own `get` function, but overload it for `std::tuple`, so people can just use your function and apply it to `std::tuple`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that there ain't no such thing as a partial specialization of function templates. So you can't partially specialize `std::tuple_element` et al for your class.

Normally, you would define free-standing functions that are logically part of your class' interface in the same namespace as the class itself. Then you can rely on argument-dependent lookup to find them. std::get would be found by that same mechanism - users of your library will not in fact be forced to write `using std::get`.

Comment: 1) std::tuple_element isn't a function. It's more like a type trait.
2) A short test I wrote showed that users would in fact have to type `using std::get`.